# marytts.exceptions.MaryConfigurationException: Cannot start MARY server

Tags: java, text-to-speech

I am trying to get Mary TTS working using Java with Eclipse. I have followed the tutorial from here so far https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLKxBorVwk8, but when I try to run the Hello World program it gives me the "Cannot start MARY server". My main code can be seen below:

```
package model;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech();
        tts.speak("Hello World!", 1.0f, false, false);
    }
}
```

The classes `TextToSpeech.java` and `AudioPlayer.java` can be found [here](https://github.com/goxr3plus/Java-Text-To-Speech-Tutorial/blob/master/Mary%20TTS%20Program/src/application/TextToSpeech.java) and [here](https://github.com/goxr3plus/Java-Text-To-Speech-Tutorial/blob/master/Mary%20TTS%20Program/src/application/AudioPlayer.java), respectively.

The few other threads I found on GitHub on this problem seemed to suggest that too many jar files have been packed into the big jar file but I tried with the jar files from the marytts GitHub page and got the same error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but to solve it, I only add the following **jar** in my project.

- guava-22.0.jar
- marytts-builder-5.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar
- marytts-lang-en-5.2.jar
- voice-cmu-rms-hsmm-5.2.jar
- voice-cmu-slt-hsmm-5.2.jar
- voice-dfki-poppy-hsmm-5.2.jar